# inner product space and orthonormal vectors

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let (S,(f,g)) be an inner product space, and let $(v_n)_{n\in{\mathbb N}}$ be an orthonormal set of vectors.

Show that, though ($v_n$) is a bounded sequence in norm, there is no subsequence which converges.

Do I have to go about using the idea that this type of space is not compact? any ideas would help.

Comment: Since an inner product space is in particular a metric space, precisely what you are asked to show is that the space is not compact. This problem should yield to a direct proof from the definitions.

Comment: Compute the distance between two arbitrary distinct points in the sequence. Then consider, how can a subsequence be Cauchy, let alone convergent?

Comment: How do I go about showing that $lim_{n\to{\infty}}$ 1/N $\sum$ $u_n$=0 in the norm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just compute that if $n\ne m$, then $$\|v_n-v_m\|=\sqrt2.$$

Comment: why is computing that useful?

Comment: To shows that the sequence $\{v_n\}$ has no convergent subsequence.

Comment: great counterexample, thanks